Flow Decision Passing when it should fail
I have a Flow that runs on new case emails - in this unique use case, we are simply ensuring some basic fields are completed, and then auto-closing the case. Recently, the decision path that should indicate that we are missing data and send an email alert is incorrectly routing through the Default path for No Missing Data, but then failing at the next step because the Case Owner field cannot be set as blank (by default the case is delivered to a Queue, but we want it updated to a specific user).
The issue for all errors recently has been that on the Account, we have not assigned an Implementation Manager yet. Therefore, it should route through the "Missing Data' path, based on the third condition. The first two conditions are FALSE, but the last SHOULD evaluate as TRUE.
Any ideas what is happening here? TIA for the help!


Have you tried debugging it?https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_flow_debugging_sbu

You need to use the IsBlank operator rather than "Equals empty string".
Empty string is different from NULL value, and IsBlank covers both.

is there a link with documentation for it?

I added the link.
